# Measure the phase of a quantum field?

Tags: berry-pancharatnam-phase

Is it possible to measure the phase of a quantum field or quantum particle, as an observable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some sense, yes.

But one can only measure a difference of phase. For example, interferences between two Bose-Einstein condensate can be interpreted as interferences due to the relative phase between the wave function of the two gases (in a good approximation, all the atoms of each gas are described by only one wave function). Another closely related example is the superfluid velocity (of a superfluid system), which is related to the gradient of the phase of the superfluid.

Yet another example, a Josephson junction allows to measure the relative phase of the order parameter of two superconducting piece of metal.